# Resizing of DOM elements in AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In my template i have a layout as such:

```
<div id="container">
    <div resizable id="subContainer1">
        <div objWrapper id="objWrapper1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="subContainer2">
        <div id="objWrapper2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

subContainer1 calls a directive that uses jqueryUI. resizable

objWrapper1 calls a directive that loads an object to the page. That object will auto resize itself to fit the containing div.

Also elsewhere on the page I have reference to another directive that loads up buttons to resize the dom elements to preset sizes.

I have 2 problems right now.

1) When I drag the corner of subContainer1 it will resize but its child dom elements do not.

2) Once I drag the corner to resize the preset buttons will change the size of the object but no longer affect the encasing dom elements